# How to compile MySQL example plugin in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-5.6, plugins

I need to compile fulltext parser plugin in windows, but I am not able to dot it even with original MySQL source example. MySQL Server version is 5.6 x64. With gcc I tried variations of:

```
 gcc -shared -Wall -g -o "plugin_example.dll" -fPIC "plugin_example.c" -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN -lmysqlservices
```

but when I try to install it

```
 INSTALL PLUGIN simple_parser SONAME 'plugin_example.dll'
```

I get following error

```
 Can't open shared library '... plugin_example.dll' (errno: 193 )
```

With Dev-C and its (stripped -L libs)

```
gcc.exe -c projekt3.c -o projekt3.o -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN -DBUILDING_DLL=1
dllwrap.exe --output-def libProjekt3.def --implib libProjekt3.a projekt3.o  -static-libgcc -lmysqlservices --no-export-all-symbols --add-stdcall-alias -o Projekt3.dll
```

I get 250K DLL and

```
Can't find symbol '_mysql_plugin_interface_version_' in library
```

Five days of googling a trial-erroring leads me nowhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: googling tells that errno 193 means wrong file format, probably an inconsistency between your 64 bit Mysql and the .dll. Can you either try with a 32-bit Mysql or compile the plugin for 64-bit or check if the install routine has some assumptions about 64 or 32 bits ?

Comment: @sqlab Thats it! Week of trying non-senses just because of this. Please post this as an full answer (maybe with link to err:193). So I can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

errno 193 means wrong file format.
Probably there is an inconsistency between your 64 bit MySQL and the .dll. Most of the the pages from Google are talking about incompatible 32-bit and 64-bit Java versions.
So I recommend either trying with a 32-bit MySQL, compiling the plugin for 64-bit or checking if the install routine has some assumptions about 64 or 32 bits ?

Comment: Compiling with mingw64 and -m64 switch did the trick. Link to page about x86/64 incompatibilites in shared libraries would be appreciated.

Comment: I have no valid links, just hints e.g. https://resource.microstrategy.com/Forum/ReplyListPage.aspx?id=32839

Answer (score 1):

I found a small sample here: http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql/creating-a-mysql-plugin-to-produce-an-interger-timestamp

Basically it is for a nix system, but you could do the same on Windows.

`gcc -Idrive:\path\to\mysql\include\ -fPIC -shared -o plugin_example.dll plugin_example.c`

Then copy it to the plugin lib

drive:\path\to\mysql\lib\plugin\

then you create the function like so:

`create function inttime RETURNS REAL SONAME 'plugin_example.dll';`

You can find the whole shebang here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/udf-compiling.html